# Utilizar APIs de G-Suite en un WCF

Tags: c#, soap, wcf

Me encuentro desarrollando un servicio SOAP con el que hago varias funciones con las APIs de G-Suite y funciona perfectamente durante el desarrollo pero al montarlo en el IIS termina dando este error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=797648014474-0itto4b52c8l40pl6ohngb5faju1r9ir.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A61193%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar" for authorization. See inner exception for details.
```

Según he investigado esto se debe a que uso credenciales de aplicación de escritorio cuando debería de usar de aplicación web, sin embargo todas las soluciones que he encontrado son para ASP.NET.

Este seria el código que uso actualmente para la autenticación:

```
string credPath = $"{ruta}/{Environment.UserName}-calendarToken.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                    calendarScopes,
                    Environment.UserName,
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

calendarService = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
```